# exclude particular file from bash_completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a simple `bash_completion` code. The only thing it does, is when I type `grcat` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it offers to complete filenames from `/etc/grcat`.

```
_grcat() {
    local word
    COMPREPLY=()
    if [ 1 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
      pushd /etc/grcat &>/dev/null || return 1
      word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f "$word"))
      popd &>/dev/null
    fi
} 
complete -F _grcat grcat
```

I need to modify it so that it lists all files from `/etc/grcat`, except `/etc/grcat/README`.

How can I make `bash_completion` ignore one particular file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `-X` option with `compgen`:

```
_grcat() {
  local word
  COMPREPLY=()
  if [ 1 -eq "$COMP_CWORD" ]; then
    pushd /etc/grcat &>/dev/null || return 1
    word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local filterpat='README'
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -X "$filterpat" -- "$word"))
    popd &>/dev/null
  fi
} 
complete -F _grcat grcat
```

`compgen` accepts most of same options as `complete`, except `-p` and `-r`.

`compgen` also generates the result, write the matches to standard output. `complete` only stores rules for future use.

Comment: that is strange. It still shows `README`, when I copy and paste your code exactly

Comment: @MartinVegter: Fixed it! Since you have been in `/etc/grcat`, so we only need `README` as pattern to ignore.

Comment: perfect! Works now.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16904329/1742825), I see that the variable that you are looking for is `FIGNORE`. You can do something like,

```
export FIGNORE=$FIGNORE:/etc/grcat/README
```

It seems you could also use `Complete` command to accomplish what you are trying to do. I see the information regarding the usage of `Complete` command from [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240388/1742825).

You can actually try modifying the `complete` command that you have in your script as something like,

```
complete -f -X '/etc/grcat/README' grcat
```

From man page of `complete`,

> -X filterpat filterpat is a pattern as used for  filename  expansion. It is applied to the list of possible completions generated by the
>   preceding options and  arguments,  and  each
>   completion  matching filterpat is removed from the list. A leading !
>   in filterpat negates the  pattern;  in  this case,  any completion not
>   matching filterpat is removed.

Comment: how do I integrate it in my `bash_completion` code. Obviously, I don't want to export `FIGNORE` for all bash. I only want to apply it to the running instance of bash completion.

Comment: @MartinVegter, you can use the `X` flag to ignore patterns. See my edit.